# Почему не активируется связь в Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

У меня есть модель из 4 таблиц и календарь.
[Исходный файл.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1paIplvgLE3zXKNCIRm_GR2msgQ6CKx1u/view?usp=sharing)
Схема следующая:

[image: представление модели]

Проблема заключается в следующем: я не могу активировать связь:
users.user_id - sessions.mentor_id.

Для наглядности (моя конечная задача перенести имя региона для mentor в тыблицу sessions) я переношу id для mentor из таблцы users в таблицу mentee.

```
# в этом столбце отражен id mentee, переданный по активной связи
mentee = 
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE(users[user_id]))

# USERELATIONSHIP не работает и id передается по активной связи
mentor = 
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE(users[user_id]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('sessions'[mentor_id], users[user_id]))
```

Вот результат:
[image: таблица]

Как заставить работать неактивную связь в данном случае?
Или в этом случае следует использовать join?

P. S. Для всех столбцов с ID установлен текстовый тип данных.